# iCalendar text encoding

Tags: encoding, icalendar

I'm creating `.ics` file. 
`iCalendar` code looks like this :

```html
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Chris/practice//
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:mytimezone
  ... something ...
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:0
DTSTART;TZID="mytimezone":20160326T140000
DTSTAMP;TZID="mytimezone":20162615T012602
LOCATION:my location             (written in my language)
SUMMARY:my summary               (written in my language)
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:1
DTSTART;TZID="mytimezone":20160326T140000
DTSTAMP;TZID="mytimezone":20162615T012602
LOCATION:my location             (written in my language)
SUMMARY:my summary               (written in my language)
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
  ... more events ...
END:VCALENDAR
```

I checked above `.ics` file on my Android device. 
Everything is fine. But, `text` of `SUMMARY` was like `?????`...
So, I checked this file again on notepad program (PC). 
It was fine. `text` was written in my language, not like `?????`. 
But, It is still `????` on Android device.

I tried everything that I know. 
I also added parameters `ENCODING`, `LANGUAGE`. (http://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/) 
But, It's not working... I'm so frustrated now...

p.s. `timezone` works good.

Comment: I wrote the file programmatically in JAVA

Comment: Never mind. I solved this problem myself. It was `JAVA` encoding problem.